# Как выполняются функции внутри цикла в JS?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь понять разницу между объявлениями переменных внутри цикла с помощью `var` и `let`. Подскажите, почему в этом примере в каждой итерации цикла происходит только инициализация колбека, а не инициализация и выполнение сразу? Другими словами, почему колбеки выполняются только уже после всех итераций?

```
function getUsersAvatars(userNames, cb){
  var url = "/userAvatars/";

  for(var index in userNames){
    _fetchAvatar(url + userNames[index], function(avatarUrl){
      _displayAvatar(userNames[index], avatarUrl);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: отличие `var` и `let` вы можете заметить попытавшись обратиться к соответствующей переменной **после** цикла

Comment: Отличия я понял. Но не понимаю, почему функции выполняются после последней итерации, а не во время каждой из них. Как мне подсказали на другом ресурсе, это такая особенность работы асинхронных функций. С этой темой я пока не знаком (учу JS на курсах), поэтому меня смутило поведение кода в указанном мной примере.

Comment: функция `_fetchAvatar_` выполняется на каждой итерации цикла.

Comment: да, но ведь функция-коллбек, которая выступает  вторым аргументом `_fetchAvatar`, работает иначе?

Comment: она выполняется тогда, когда решит `_fetchAvatar_` в данном случае после получения ответа от сервера.

Comment: спасибо! вот этот момент меня как раз и вводил в заблуждение. буду признателен, если подскажете, где можно почитать о порядке выполнения подробнее